# How to prevent overlapping the text of x-axis in time series?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, c3.js

I am using c3.js time series in my project . The text of x-axis is overlapping

when zoom the browser up to 500 .

How to fix it ?

Waiting for your response .

Answer (score 0):

the c3 charts have a css class

> .c3

add a styling in the css as below for text under .c3:

```
.c3 text {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I have already tried in this way but behavior was same as it was . you just change the font size and zoom your brower upto 500 then you will come to know. Please test it thoroughly  before give the answer.

Comment: if it is 0.5em no one will be able to see the text in normal mode.